# Имитация нажатия клавиш в майнкрафт на python или c++

Tags: python, c++, клавиатура, keyboardhook, ahk

Пытаюсь имитировать нажатие клавиш на python в майнкрафт(stalcraft) используя библиотеку ahk(python), но кроме поворота мышки в игре ничего не работает, пытался использовать другие библиотеки, пробовал имитировать на C++ и перебирать коды клавиш но ничего, может кто объяснить что не так и как решить проблему.

```
ahk = AHK()
win = ahk.win_get(title='window')
win.activate()
time.sleep(5)
ahk.key_press("k")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Покажите код...

Comment: добавил код....